# Как побороть ReflectionException Class app\modules\module_name\module does not exist?

Tags: yii2

Написал простое приложение. Оно работает из под винды + апач + мускуль. Нареканий никаких. 
Все решил потестировать на хостинге, залил все файлы, изменил бд, пользователя и пароль на нужное, залил структуру бд и некоторые данные таблиц.

На хостинге стоит нгинкс. Пробую запустить и получаю ошибку:
ReflectionException
Class app\modules\str\module does not exist
Даже не знаю в чем может быть проблема. Все же работало на сервере из под винды, а на линуксе не сработало. Прошу указать на возможные ошибки знающим

Answer (score 0):

вопрос закрыт, нужно было изменить имя файла модуля с Module на module. В очередной раз линукс порадовал. С другой стороны это делалось с помощью gii. Кодогенератор сплоховал.

Comment: Вряд ли прям в этом причина. У меня все файлы Module.php и проекты на ubuntu.